# Find a Portion of a Database in Ruby

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, object, where-clause

Say for example I have the following database of instances of a class called `Obj`:

```
| id | attr1 |
+----+-------+
| 10 |   A   |
| 15 |   B   |
| 20 |   C   |
| 50 |   D   |
```

Now let's say I want to find all of the instances of `Obj` with id greater than 10. How would I do that?

I want to write `Obj.where(id > 10).all`. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try:

```
Obj.where("id > ?", 10)
```

you will find different ways to retrieve data from the database using Active Record from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Obj.where("id > ?", 10)
```